# Sending SAML response

Tags: java, saml-2.0

I am starting to develop a small servlet that create a SAML response from a SAML request. I have finally been able to gerenate the response but I don't know how to send it. I know I have to send it with POST method but I would like to know if I must encode the SAML string before sending it...I try to send it in a form but the service provider does not accept it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you BASE-64 encoding the response before you send it to the Service Provider? Encode the value before you put it in the Form